# Android Emulator is not working

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i run the emulator is running up to the process big text android. After that is not responding. In Eclipse console showing  text "Wait for Home"  I tried re-install of android also

My System properties Microsoft Windows XP, 0.99GB of RAM

Any help me for this problem Advanced Thanks

Comment: Is this your first time running the emulator?

Comment: Wait for the emulator to start up max 3 minutes. It's simply slow. If it won't run after 3 min. then write about it.

Comment: I wait for 2 hours its not responding

Answer (score 1):

Don't rush to reinstall the SDK. Try creating a new AVD with the same API level that your original one had and run your app on that one. If that's OK just delete the original one as its image may be corrupted. You won't lose anything and it's not worth spending time on trying to fix it.

**Edited:**

```
The solution which worked for me is, when you get the message

Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

wait for few seconds and then right click on the project and click run as android application once again.
```

Answer (score 1):

The emulator takes a long time to load the first time, several minutes, and in this time only shows 'Android' in large text. Wait a couple of minutes and then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your SD card file is large enough. I've found the minimum Eclipse enforces (9MB) isn't enough for it to boot.

You may also have to use a different computer or upgrade your RAM. Modern phones have around 500MB RAM, so .99 GB maybe not be enough to go around for Eclipse, Windows XP, and the emulator.

As a last resort, you could reformat. I was having a similar problem and it worked after reformatting.

Answer (score 0):

I once had similar problem. This solution worked for me. When I launch the emulator, I chose *wipe user data* option on the *launch options* window. Hope this help.