# Android Emulator won't work

Tags: android, emulation

When I run the android emulator it gets stuck on the android animation. After I have waited 1 hour it said **"Proccess system is not responding"**. I've tried to delete it and create a new one but it didn't work. I want to start android developing but I'm about to give up because nothing works. Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There're lots of reasons could be. But there is another and easier option: Genymotion http://www.genymotion.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535196/android-emulator-is-not-working

Comment: @Mehedi-PSTU Tried it already.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing the avd. or better still you can use an android device an Emulator, which is better and faster. to use an android device follow this steps.
1. Get an android device and a usb cable.
2. Go to settings on your android device and select developer options.
       If your device does not have the developer options, goto about phone and click on **Build number** 7 times., go back to settings (Developer options would have appered by then)
select developer options, turn it on and enable debugging.
3. plug your device into your system.
4. your phone will notify you on access to degug.. Accept.
5. Close any avd you might have opened before..
6. Run your app..
You are good too go...The app should run on your android device..
BUILD NICE APPPPPPPPPSSSSSSSS